# Using LDAP on Tiki-Wiki

Tags: tiki-wiki

I am using Tiki-Wiki to create a wiki for my company. I need users authentication using LDAP. When I click on the LDAP tab on the Admin Login page, the LDAP tab disappears and only the General Preferences tab is visible. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the "Advanced" checked under `Preference Filters`.  What browser are you using?  Also be sure you don't have javascript disabled.